# Jquery Iframe textbox

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery, In fact, I have 0 knowledge using JQuery. I am trying to get something to work using JQuery.

I have a html page with an iframe. The iframe page has a form in it and a textbox in it.
The Iframe is actually created by another jquery function and is inside a div.

Now, when I click a link on the main page, I want the textbox in the iframe to be populated with some value. Is it possible to get this to work?

```
<html>
....
...
<a click="populate()">Populate IFrame</a>
....
...
<div id="iframediv"></div>
...
```

...

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work:

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#mytextbox').val("myvalue");
```